# Mocking constructor of $resource object in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mocha.js, sinon

I'm using AngularJS and my tests are in mocha+sinon+chai

The code I'm trying to test looks like this:

```
addModal.result.then(function (clientFeature) {
                if (clientFeature) {
                    //create a new $resource ClientFeature object with result
                    var newClientFeature = new ClientFeature(clientFeature);
                    //push newly created clientfeature to list
                    $scope.clientFeatures.push(newClientFeature);

                    //make REST call to create new clientfeature
                    newClientFeature.$save({clientId: newClientFeature.client.id}, function (data, headers) {
                        console.log('created.');
                        console.log(data);
                    }, null);
                }
});
```

ClientFeature is a $resource object:

'use strict';

```
angular.module('yrdyApp')
    .factory('ClientFeature', function ($resource, $location) {
        return $resource('https://' + $location.host() + ':port/clientfeatures/client/:clientId', {port: ':3333', clientId: '@clientId'}, {
            update: {method: 'PUT'}
        });
    });
```

How do I mock out this line?

```
//create a new $resource ClientFeature object with result
var newClientFeature = new ClientFeature(clientFeature);
```

My existing mocks:

```
        // set up mocks
    ClientFeatureMock = {
        query: sinon.spy(),
        update: sinon.stub()
    };

    // mock client feature object
    clientFeature = {
        client: {
            id: 100
        },
        $update: sinon.spy(),
        $save: sinon.spy()
    };
```

Thanks,
Shaun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the recommended way of doing things, but I decided to not stub/mock the service. Instead, I'm injecting the actual service, and spying on individual methods + setting up httpBackend to intercept http requests.

```
// Initialize the controller and a mock scope
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, _$timeout_, $q, $httpBackend, _ClientFeature_) {

    // inject actual service
    ClientFeature = _ClientFeature_;

    // set up httpBackend behavior
    httpBackend = $httpBackend;        
    httpBackend.whenGET(/https:\/\/.+\/clientfeatures\/client\/./).respond(200, []);

    // set up mocks
    ClientFeatureMock = {
        query: sinon.spy(ClientFeature, 'query')
    };
```

And an example test:

```
it('should start by retrieving a list of clientfeatures for a client', function () {
    // flush/make the http call
    httpBackend.flush();
    ClientFeatureMock.query.should.be.called;
});
```